# Tree Table parsing with linq trouble

Tags: c#, database, linq

I have a table in db with PK(id) - int, FK(ParentDepID) int, and DepartmentName (Varchar). This is tree of departments connections.The problems are
- find the number of elements of first level for each department
-select all departments that have NO child departments
-select all departments that HAVE child departments.
 I am new in linq really(( help me to solve this problem and also recommend something to read about sql - linq. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you know how to use LINQ in your solution, if that is not the case you'll want to look at some starter tutorials such as [this basic LINQ to SQL scenario](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386940.aspx) and [this how to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399375.aspx) on connecting a DataContext to the database. Once your DataContext is set up, you can start writing [LINQ Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx).

The query for your first problem would then be:

```
var firstLevelQuery =   from d in db.Departments 
                        where d.ParentDepID == null
                        select d;
```

This finds all departments in your table that don't have a `ParentDepID` and are therefore root nodes on your tree. To count how many of these there are, use `firstLevelQuery.Count();`. You can work with these as an `IQueryable<Department>` or you can cast them to a list with `List<Department> firstLevelDepartments = firstLevelQuery.ToList();`.

Finding departments that are parents is trickier, and we have to use multiple queries here. We first find all the IDs that are referenced in the departments table, and then look for all departments that match one of those IDs.

```
var innerQuery = from d in db.Departments select d.ParentDepID;
var parents =   from p in db.Departments
                where innerQuery.Contains<int>(p.ParentDepID)
                select p;
```

You should be able to get records that aren't parents by negating the Contains statement: `where !innerQuery.Contains<int>(m.GameTypeId)`